# Can Attributes target a specific field of an object field?

Tags: c#, attributes

Attributes provide the `field` attribute target.
This however only seems to help when targeting the backing field of an auto-property.

If I add an attribute to a specific object field, the type of the field is known at compile time. Is there a way to target that attribute at fields on that type?

Example:

```cs
// class in my code
public class Foo
{
    [field: SomeAttribute] // <-- this should target TargetClass.TargetField, is it possible and how?
    public Bar TargetClass;
    
}

// class that might be defined in a library or part of code that I cannot edit or add attributes to
public class Bar
{
    public int TargetField;
}
```

I've looked through the Attribute documentation, but can't find anything related to this particular usecase. This leads me to think it's not directly supported.

However, intuitively I would think the compiler has all the information necessary to make this kind of targeting possible so maybe this is something that has been suggested but isn't implemented yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a thing you can do. The attribute would need to be on the actual type/member intended. There *is* a concept of runtime properties in the "descriptor" model (rather than the reflection model) which would allow more flexibility, but that only applies in niche scenarios, so honestly: it isn't worth trying to explain.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I was thinking. In my case both the attribute and the objects come from separate libraries that I can't edit so I suppose I'm out of luck here.

The attribute is used to mark specific serializable fields to be included in an UI form so without this functionality I think I just need to separately include a duplicate field and replicate its changes to the object's fields manually whenever a change is applied.

I'll wait a few more days before accepting this answer in case someone provides potential workarounds but this does answer my question.

Comment: Seems like this question is getting no more traction so marked this answer as accepted.